# C++11 : Does new return contiguous memory?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
float* tempBuf = new float[maxVoices]();
```

Will the above result in

1) memory that is 16-byte aligned?

2) memory that is confirmed to be contiguous?

What I want is the following:

```
float tempBuf[maxVoices] __attribute__ ((aligned));
```

but as heap memory, that will be effective for Apple Accelerate framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The memory will be aligned for `float`, but not necessarily for CPU-specific SIMD instructions. I strongly suspect on your system `sizeof(float) < 16`, though, which means it's not as aligned as you want. The memory will be contiguous: `&A[i] == &A[0] + i`.

If you need something more specific, `new std::aligned_storage<Length, Alignment>` will return a suitable region of memory, presuming of course that you did in fact pass a more specific alignment.

Another alternative is `struct FourFloats alignas(16) {float[4] floats;};` - this may map more naturally to the framework. You'd now need to do `new FourFloats[(maxVoices+3)/4]`.

Comment: Hi thanks I changed the question to alignment to 16 bytes.

Comment: typedef std::aligned_storage<32,16>::type AlignedFloatBuf;
       float* tempBuf = (float*)new AlignedFloatBuf; //-- Is this the way to use aligned_storage? The problem with this is that I can't put maxVoices*sizeof(float) where 32 is.

Comment: To be specific (§[expr.new]): "It is implementation-defined whether over-aligned types are supported (3.11).", where "over-aligned" is defined as(§[basic.align]): "...an alignment greater than alignof(std::max_align_t)."

Comment: @ippier make an array of aligned storages.

Comment: @lppier: Presumably `maxVoices` is not an Integral Constant Expression?

Comment: nope, it's a int variable, but set on initialisation of the class when it's invoked.

Comment: @lppier: That means the compiler won't know the value, and cannot instantiate the template. You'll need the `maxVoices/4` method.

Comment: Does float *tempBuf;
posix_memalign(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&tempBuf), 16, maxVoices * sizeof(float)); do the trick then? I know it's not C++11, but I'm not picky.

Comment: @lppier: Looks good to me, but please don't append additional questions to an existing question. SO is free, and it's a decent-enough question IMO, so just post it as a new question (do link back to this question for background)

Comment: @MSalters sure thing, removed.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `new` returns contiguous memory.

As for alignment, no such alignment guarantee is provided.  Try this:

```
template<class T, size_t A>
T* over_aligned(size_t N){
  static_assert(A <= alignof(std::max_align_t),
    "Over-alignment is implementation-defined."
  );
  static_assert( std::is_trivially_destructible<T>{},
    "Function does not store number of elements to destroy"
  );
  using Helper=std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), A>;
  auto* ptr = new Helper[(N+sizeof(Helper)-1)/sizeof(Helper)];
  return new(ptr) T[N];
}
```

Use:

```
float* f = over_aligned<float,16>(37);
```

Makes an array of 37 floats, with the buffer aligned to 16 bytes.  Or it fails to compile.

If the assert fails, it can still work.  Test and consult your compiler documentation.  Once convinced, put compiler-specific version guards around the static assert, so when you change compilers you can test all over again (yay).

If you want real portability, you have to have a fall back to `std::align` and manage resources separately from data pointers *and* count the number of `T` if and only if `T` has a non-trivial destructor, then store the number of `T` "before" the start of your buffer.  It gets pretty silly.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's guaranteed to be aligned properly with respect to the type you're allocating. So if it's an array of 4 `float`s (each supposedly 4 bytes), it's guaranteed to provide a usable sequence of `float`s. It's *not* guaranteed to be aligned to 16 bytes.
2. Yes, it's guaranteed to be contiguous (otherwise what would be the meaning of a single pointer?)

If you want it to be aligned to some *K* bytes, you can do it manually with [`std::align`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align). See [MSalter's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35273895/602372) answer for a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: The problem with `std::align` is that it eats up to `K-1` bytes.

Comment: Yes, you would have to allocate more. Your answer in that aspect is better, because it gives the allocator a trait it can use to optimize stuff.

Comment: @MSalters However, I'll leave that as just your answer, for diversity. Or maybe you can add the relevant parts of mine (if you find it useful), and I can delete my answer. It's better to have one complete answer, I think.

Comment: Leave your answer; the StackOverflow process is to let the audience vote on what they think is the best. But what's best may vary from case to case, so we don't delete answers just because. (We only delete answers when there are serious issues, like spam/abuse)

Comment: @MSalters Okay, referenced it, then.

Answer (score 0):

If `tempBuf` is not `nullptr` then the C++ standard guarantees that `tempBuf` points to the zeroth element of least `maxVoices` contiguous `float`s.

(Don't forget to call `delete[] tempBuf` once you're done with it.)

Comment: `tmpBuf` can't be a null pointer. Unless you use the `nothrow` variant of `new`, it will either succeed or throw.